# Nagios: Disable Host notifcation but enable service notification for local printers

Tags: nagios, network-monitoring

Is it possible to enable notifications for services in NAGIOS but to disable hosts notifications? I have a lot of local printers which don't have a impact when they are down but I want to have a service notification e.g. for "no paper" or "low toner cartridge".

Any experiences? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of options, you can create a new host template to use for printers that inherits from your generic-host template, but turn off the setting to enable host notifications with:

```
notifications_enabled           0
```

E.g.

```
define host{
    name                    generic-printer
    use                     generic-host
    notifications_enabled   0
    register                0
}
```

Then each printers host definition could include the line

```
use                     generic-printer
```

in its definition.

Alternately, you could create a brand new printer template similar to the one for `generic-host` with `notifications_enabled` disabled and also not including any entry for `check_command` (which is where the command used to determine if a host is OK is chosen).

Answer (score 0):

Default checks like `ping` or `ssh` can be disabled by deleting the service definition in the corresponding machine's `.cfg` file in the monitoring host. `nrpe` or `nrdp` services can be used for checks like low toner cartrige or no paper.

Steps to remove the ping check for `printer1`:

1- Open the `printer1.cfg` file in the nagios server to edit. (Usually under `.../nagios/configurations/objects/`)

2- Find the service definition in `printer1.cfg` where `service_description` value is `PING` and delete this definition.

3- Restart NagiOS. After this, the ping check should not be visible from the nagios web interface too.